# How to adapt a class to use with xelatex/lualatex?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I have a custom .cls written (by somebody else) for use specifically with `pdfLaTex` engine. However, I want to compile my document with `xe` or `lua` for the sake of font support (and I don't want to use `tipa`).

Where should I start in order to figure out if this class can be adapted for my prefered engines?

Comment: just try it, and handle any errors that come up? I don't see what other answer can be given to such a vague/general question.

Comment: At the begin of the class? Your question is much to vage for an sensible answer.

Comment: I would think that there should be something particular, like a declaration or something? I didn't realize it was just so specific to each class -- are suggesting that?

Comment: @JPi: To late ;-). (Sometimes the german spelling wins ...).

Comment: @IvanKapitonov the vast majority of classes require no change at all, why do you think this one does? Certainly as we have not seen it we can give no advice at all.

Comment: @Ulrike: same in Dutch.... ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you -- that's helpful enough. I was reading the class manual and it said the class was specifically for pdfLaTeX. Now I will bravely compile and look into the problems, if any. Thank you!